# name 'context' is not defined

Tags: django, django-views

I try to use a view to create a table (which I later want to populate with data). But if I open the respective url the view creates a "name 'context' is not defined" error. Can anybody explain?

```
def room_overview(request, year, month):
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    long_month = ['01', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12']
    short_month = ['04','06','09','11']
    if month in long_month:
        month_max = 31
    elif month in short_month:
        month_max = 30
    elif year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
        month_max = 29
    else:
        month_max = 28

    days = []
    for i in range(1, month_max + 1):
        days.append(str(i))

    context['rooms'] = rooms
    context['days'] = days
    context['month'] = month
    context['year'] = year

    return render(request, 'hotel/overview.html', context)
```

the template for the view looks like this:

```
<h2>Overview {{month}}/{{year}}:</h2>
<div class="overview">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        {% for day in days %}
        <th>day</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

{% for room in rooms %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ room.name }}</td>
    {% for day in days %}
    <td> 1 </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

this is the url entry:

```
url(r'^room/overview/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$',views.room_overview, name='room_overview'),
```

Comment: You assign directly to your `context` dict, here first: `context['rooms'] = rooms`. *But your `context` dict doesn't exist yet! Create it (empty) first.

Comment: The error message should point you pretty directly to the line where the error occurs. That should have been a dead give away.

Comment: I have a ton of other views in the same app where I didn't create an empty context dict first and it created no error whatsoever. But thanks it worked.

Comment: Then the code in those other views is different: you can't simply instantiate a dict that way. Try using the development server and `print(context)` as the first line of those views where it does work; unless it's a global variable (bad idea), it will crash.

Answer (score 5):

You must define your context variable first before you add key/value pairs.

You can do this:

```
context = {}
context['rooms'] = rooms
context['days'] = days
context['month'] = month
context['year'] = year
```

or, the way I personally prefer:

```
context = {
    'rooms': rooms, 
    'days': days,
    'month': month,
    'year': year,
}
```

and this will solve your error.